# Symfony 4 Как передать массив из контроллера в форму

Tags: php, ооп, symfony

Имеется код (файл "названиеТаблицыType.php"):

```
class TankUpgradeType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $tankIdName = array(
            "name1" => 1,
            "name2" => 2,
            "name3" => 3,
            "name4" => 4,
        );
        $builder
            ->add('idTank', ChoiceType::class, array( 'choices'  => $tankIdName, ))
}
```

тут я создаю ассоциативный массив для ChoiceType чтоб пользователь выбирал имя а в базу запихивался айди, с этим нет проблем, даже знаю как составить такой массив, мой пример

```
use App\Entity\Tank;
public function index(TablesRepository $tablesRepository): Response
{
    $entityManager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $tanks = $entityManager->getRepository(Tank::class)->findAll(); //получаю все записи из Tank и записываю в обьект $tanks
    foreach ($tanks as $tank) {

        $tankName[] = $tank->getTankName();        //получаем имя танка
        $tankId[] = $tank->getId();               //получаем id танка

    }
    $tankIdName = array_combine($tankName, $tankId);
    var_dump($tankIdName);
```

тут вар дамп выведет массив, все проверил все ок, как надо, думаю сработает, как мне передать этот массив в "class TankUpgradeType extends AbstractType" с симфони и ООП недавно, не ругайте особо =(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Передавать массивы никуда не надо.

Если вы работаете с симфони4 то запомните симфонический подход - все реализуется через `Dependency Injection`.

Если ваша форма зависит от списка танков, значит надо передать в форму некий объект, что вернет список танков. Передача объектов осуществляется через конструктор (да, у вашего FormType есть конструктор). Далее используйте переданный объект через `$this`.

Теперь вам надо понять - а что собственно инжектить? Что может вам вернуть список танков? В простейшем случае - репозиторий:

```
class TankUpgradeType extends AbstractType
{

    protected $tankRepository;

    public function __construct(TankRepository $tankRepository)
    {
        $this->tankRepository = $tankRepository;
    }

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $tankIdName = [];
        $tanks = $this->tankRepository->findAll();
        foreach ($tanks as $tank) {
            // что-то там с $tankIdName
        }

        $builder
            ->add('idTank', ChoiceType::class, array( 'choices'  => $tankIdName, ))
    }
```

Чтобы не мешать логику формы с логикой генерации списка танков можно создать дополнительный сервис, это на ваше усмотрение.